# putting the caption of a table on its right

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

I have a table environment, which has a tabular environment inside, and I would like to put the caption on its right (the table is narrow enough for that), and not below it. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capbesideposition=outside,capbesidesep=quad]{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\floatbox[\capbeside]{table}
{\caption{A test table with its caption beside}\label{tab:test}}%
{\begin{tabular}{ll}
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is the [`sidecap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCtable}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
column 1a & column 2a \\
column 1b & column 2b \\
column 1c & column 2c
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test table with its caption beside}\label{tab:test}
\end{SCtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An additional remark: the KOMAScript-Classes have this functionality built in, look up the `captionbeside` environment in the manual.

Comment: Any idea how to move the caption to the middle of the table/figure, such that it does not appear in the top?