# Set Captionof table to left

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption

I am using the documentclass `scrartcl` and have a table

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} \\
\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} \\
\cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCFF2F}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Feeling irie}
\end{table}
```

[image: Screenshot]

How would I set the caption to the left?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83897/putting-the-caption-of-a-table-on-its-right

Comment: Don't use `\label` prior to `\caption`! Recommended way is to use it inside the argument of `\caption` (but watch out that you don't introduce wrong spaces).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. he is using a KOMA-class, I don't think the linked question does help.

Comment: @Skillmon Right, didn't think about the class, thanks for the comment. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97699/caption-on-the-side-of-a-table/97703#97703 is more relevant then.